# Check if travis build is a success or not

Tags: travis-ci

I am triggering travis builds through the API: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds

So I have written a script which triggers the build. But after the trigger I want to check in my script itself if the build is a success or not. How do I do this?

Or let's say I can also do this: I want to wait in my script till the build is going on. After the build is complete I want to execute the rest of my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the `Builds` entity, look for the newest build in the list, and check for it's `state` attribute: https://docs.travis-ci.com/api#builds

Comment: Suppose I trigger the build from a ruby file, can you show an example on how I can check the status of the build in `if statement`?

Comment: Nope, I know close to 0 ruby. I can only tell you to google examples yourself, follow them as far as you can and if necessary ask another question. http://railsware.com/blog/2013/09/10/capistrano-recipe-for-checking-travis-ci-build-status/